# Changing a linq query to filter on many-many

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following Linq query

```
public static List<string> selectedLocations = new List<string>();

// I then populate selectedLocations with a number of difference strings, each
// corresponding to a valid Location

viewModel.people = (from c in db.People
                    select c)
                    .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
                    .ToList();

// Here I'm basically filtering my dataset to include Locations from
// my array of selectedLocations

viewModel.people = from c in viewModel.people
                    where (
                    from a in selectedLocations
                    where a == c.Location.Name
                    select a
                    ).Any()
                    select c;
```

This works really well as each Person record can have a single Location.

My question is how do I change this query if a Person can have a one-many relationship with Location?  So a Person can have 2 Locations as an example, what do I need to change this line to?

```
where a == c.Location.Name
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try to replace this part :

```
where a == c.Location.Name
```

with this :

```
where c.Locations.Any(o => o.Name == a)
```

that will return true if any `Location` in `Locations` property has `Name` equals `a`.

Comment: Follow up question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435361/returning-blanks-in-many-to-many-linq-query